# Azure DevOps CI -Xcpretty encoding via ssh

Tags: macos, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

I'm using Azure-DevOps Server pipeline to compile an IOS application with an IOS agent (macOS Big Sur) while using Xcpretty for tests and code coverage reports. The Xcpretty not working:

> Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/parser.rb:434:in
> ===': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError) from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/parser.rb:434:in
> update_test_state' from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/parser.rb:307:in
> parse' from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/formatters/formatter.rb:88:in
> pretty_format' from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/printer.rb:19:in
> pretty_print' from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/bin/xcpretty:84:in block
> in <top (required)>' from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/bin/xcpretty:83:in
> each_line' from
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/bin/xcpretty:83:in <top
> (required)>' from /usr/local/bin/xcpretty:23:in load' from
> /usr/local/bin/xcpretty:23:in '

I'm using Azure-DevOps Server pipeline to compile an IOS application with an IOS agent (macOS Big Sur) while using Xcpretty for tests and code coverage reports. The Xcpretty not working:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/parser.rb:434:in ===': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError) from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/parser.rb:434:in update_test_state' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/parser.rb:307:in parse' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/formatters/formatter.rb:88:in pretty_format' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/printer.rb:19:in pretty_print' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/bin/xcpretty:84:in block in <top (required)>' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/bin/xcpretty:83:in each_line' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/bin/xcpretty:83:in <top (required)>' from /usr/local/bin/xcpretty:23:in load' from /usr/local/bin/xcpretty:23:in '

Everybody on google says that it about encoding but I just changed them:

[image: Here]

And still got the same error.

Any other idea?

Comment: When you build locally on your agent machine, how's the result?

Comment: Locally the result fine.

Comment: When im running "locale" from ADO bash, it showing the wrong encoding again. 
The solution was to run xcode test from bash with

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

At the top of the script, that worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to restart your SSH agent and build agent after changing the encoding.